# Define single DevExpress control namespace in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I am using DevExpress Controls in my WPF application.so now I have below namespace defined in many of XAML files.

```
 xmlns:dxg="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Grid;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v13.1"
```

Problem is whenever I need to updated DevExpress for ex: from v13.1 to v14.2. I have to update namespace in all of the XAML files. This is very tedious process.

is there anyway I can define namespace at one place and reference it in all my XAML files? So that I have to do change only at one place.

Comment: Have you tried [Project Converter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529)?

Comment: Thanks..Will check this out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project converter which is provided by devexpress.

In Visual Studio menu: Devexpress > Project converter.